# transaction successful notification

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin, transaction

Как запросить проверку о том, что транзакция была отправлена в mempool bitcoin, либо отклонена? Пакеты с reject приходят очень редко.

Поиск нод осуществляю по подобном коду:

https://github.com/ricmoo/pycoind/blob/33a600e617ec89c5a0f680ce7725b777d6176ea8/pycoind/util/bootstrap.py#L28

После получения списка нод, я отправляю им пакет с коммандой 'version':

```
s.send(make_message(b'version', version_message()))
```

В ответ получаю подобный пакет: *recv(1024).hex()[56:72]*, где *'56:72'* - это Node Services. При *True* я сохраняю ноду в список.

Последним этапом будет push tx. 
Отправляется пакет с командой 'tx', ждем ответный пакет(обычно в ответ приходит Version, Verack, ping, addr), проверяем транзакцию в mempool, если ничего не находим - идем на следующую ноду из списка. Так могу пройтись по ~20ти адресам и ничего не запушить. Иногда с первой ноды получаю успешный результат и скрипт останавливается.

Если я отправляю транзакцию на какой-нибудь blockchain explorer, то во всех случаях она была успешна. Если же отправлять на ноду, то тут полный рандом. С чем связано? Как выполнять проверку и не зависеть от blockchain explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы работаете не по стандарту. В ответ на tx не может прийти `version`/`ping`/`addr`. Эти команды приходят сами по себе, и на них нужно отвечать.

В [документации](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx) пишут:

> tx describes a bitcoin transaction, in reply to getdata.

Сначала нужно сообщить другой ноде, что у нас есть новая информация при помощи команды `inv`. Потом она должна сама запросить транзакцию командой `getdata`. Только потом можно отправлять `tx`.

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо, в моей функции 'push tx' при каждой транзакции я отправляю повторно пакет Version и следом Tx. Дописал recv(1024) после отправки пакета Version и транзакции стали проходить сразу. А в ответ на Tx ничего не приходит. Видимо из-за нарушения стандарта. 

Хотел уточнить момент:
1) Работаю по SPV.

Для корректной работы я должен обменяться с нодами пакетами Version, затем отправить Inv и на их ответный запрос предоставить необходимую информацию по tx/etc?

Comment: Когда я делал, мой клиент отправлял verack в ответ на version, pong в ответ на ping, headers в ответ на getheaders. inv я отправлял уже сам.